# How to prevent widget receiving click event when doubleclicking to maximize window?

Tags: gtk

I have a widget that reacts on click event. However, when I doubleclick on the window's title bar, it maximizes the window and very often, the mouse pointer ends up into my widget, causing it to receive an undesired click event. How can I prevent my widget to receive the click event in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do this in GTK because it is your window manager which is responsible for this bad behaviour, so either use a better WM or get it fixed (filing a bug).

If you insist on trying to solve this in gtk, you could try to see if your window receives a mouse-down event before a mouse-up (rather than the pressed event alone) - no guarantees this will even do anything useful!